# User defined reports in DBeaver

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I am using the Oracle SQL developer tool and would like to switch to DBeaver(to use different DBs in the single editor). As an Oracle SQL developer, I am using a user-defined reports script. But I couldn't find the same thing in DBeaver. Where can I upload my script in DBeaver?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**User Defined Reports** is a proprietary extension built-in to SQL Developer. It isn't compatible with DBeaver and other SQL clients. And in general, most SQL clients don't offer rich reporting capabilities with charts and PDF options. It's the kind of feature that you tend to find in BI tools like SAS or Tableau.

The reports themselves are stored locally on your computer in a `UserReports.xml` file [link 1](https://dbaontap.com/2014/08/25/migrate-your-sql-developer-user-defined-reports/) [link 2](https://github.com/gwenshap/SQLDeveloper/blob/master/UserReports.xml)

If you just want a custom library of SQL scripts that you can run, DBeaver organizes your work into [Projects](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Projects/), and each project contains a [Scripts folder](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Script-Management/) where you can store your own scripts. You can right-click on Scripts and click Properties to see where they're stored locally  on your computer.

[image: screenshot of an example Project Scripts folder]